# How do I get rid of the new message layout from Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'm having a hard time to adjusting to the new messages format in Facebook. I want to revert to the old messages format. How do I remove it? There is no option under Facebook account settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, probably not. Even if you were able to revert, it would only last until FB rolls out the new layout and makes it mandatory. I imagine that this is already the case.

Feel free to browse the info about the new features and layout: https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=260810124034353